# 画像をiPhoneのフォルダから取得する

Tags: monaca, api

ToDoアプリのテンプレートにある写真撮影機能にiPhoneのフォルダにある写真を選べる機能を追加したいのですが、

```
function addTodoPicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(addTodo, function() {
        alert("Failed to get camera.");
    }, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth : 100,
        targetHeight : 100
    });
}
function addTodo(camera_url) {
    var title = $("#todo-title").val();
    var body = $("#todo-body").val();
    var img_tag = "";
    if (camera_url) {
        img_tag = "<img src='" + camera_url + "'>";
    }
    $.mobile.changePage($("#list-page"));
    $("#todo-list").append("<li>" + img_tag + "<h3>" + title + "</h3><p>" + body + "</p></li>")
    $("#todo-list").listview('refresh');
};
```

このテンプレートに、Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY をどのように組み込めば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

写真撮影とアルバムからの選択については自分で分岐をつくるとして、
選択処理自体は[ここ（Monaca Docs）](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/en/sampleapp/tips/camera/)の「Obtain Pictures from a Device’s Album」に書いてあるコードをコピペしてcallbackの部分だけ変更すればいけませんか？
※とりあえずデバッガで写真選択するところまでは確認できました。

```
function getPhoto () {
  //Specify the source to get the photos.
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
    { quality: 50,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM });
}
```